# Nonlinear anomalous Hall effect

Tags: condensed-matter

Has there been any research on anomalous Hall effect which would observe or predict a non-constant dependence of the AHE conductivity on the applied electric field?

Comment: Do you mean the longitudinal voltage? The AHE is not very well defined, but typically the AHE is proportional to the Magnetisation.